# Формы от слова "бакалавр"

Tags: стилистика

Слово *бакалавр* все чаще встречается в нащей жизни. Недавно прочитала сочетание: "Бакалаврская программа". Звучит как-то сомнительно, но другой формы для прилагательного не подберу.

Можно, конечно, сказать" программа подготовки бакалавров", но это совсем уж официальный вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это "программа" называется бакалавриат. А вообще прилагательное образовано правильно. Лопатин фиксирует.